# Where does Excel get Username from in "Environ("Username")"? And how to edit it?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I'm utilizing the **Environ("Username")** function in an excel file to determine the user that is logged in. But I thought that the username is being extracted from the mail id of the user logged in. But I have noticed that for some of my colleagues, the username and the mail id doesn't match. 
That is when my colleague pointed out that the username in Environ("Username") and the Alias in Your info section*(Settings>Accounts>Your info)* in the Windows settings match.

[image: Windows Settings>Accounts>Your Info]

So I was wondering if this is where the Username is being extracted from, and if yes how can we edit it?

*P.S: this is in reference to an Office 365 account.*

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/371382/where-is-username-variable-defined.

Comment: For me the user name in the "Your info" screen is not the same as the one of the "username" environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and type `cmd` to launch a command prompt. From there, type `set` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
These are all the variables that can be retrieved by `Environ()`

Not sure you can edit that: you can type `SET username = xyz` in the command prompt, then if do a set, il will list the new value, but that seems to be a local copy, not visible from Excel VBA for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incomplete answer and only meant as help in pointing to a more final answer:

It returns the user name which matches what you find under `C:\Users\`.
Patrick Honorez' answer provides you with the active user if there are more than one profiles available.